# What does it mean for an ultrafilter to have a limit?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, filters

I got this question from the construction of the Stone-Čech compactification using ultrafilters given in Wikipedia. There they say that if $F$ is an ultrafilter in a compact Hausdorff space $K$ then it has a unique limit.

I can see this in the case $F$ is principal. It makes sense to think about a limit of an ultrafilter $F$ as a common limit point to all subsets which are in $F$. If $F$ is principal, clearly there is only one such limit point, namely the generator.

If $F$ is not principal, then all subsets in $F$ are infinite, and by compactness of $K$ one can find subsequence for each of these subsets that has a limit point (unique by Hausdorffness). But how do I see that there is one unique limit point for a subsequence of each subset in $F$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mathscr{U}$ be an ultrafilter in the compact space $X$. Let $\mathscr{F}=\{\operatorname{cl}U:U\in\mathscr{U}\}$; then $\mathscr{F}\subseteq\mathscr{U}$, so $\mathscr{F}$ is a family of closed sets with the finite intersection property. Since $X$ is compact, $\bigcap\mathscr{F}\ne\varnothing$. Let $x\in\bigcap\mathscr{F}$; if $V$ is any open nbhd of $x$, and $U\in\mathscr{U}$, then $V\cap\operatorname{cl}U\ne\varnothing$, so $V\cap U\ne\varnothing$. Thus, $\mathscr{U}\cup\{V\}$ is a filter, and since $\mathscr{U}$ is an ultrafilter, this means that $\mathscr{U}\cup\{V\}=\mathscr{U}$, i.e., that $V\in\mathscr{U}$. Thus, every open nbhd of $x$ is in $\mathscr{U}$, which by definition means that $\mathscr{U}\to x$.

If $X$ is also Hausdorff, this limit point is unique, because $\bigcap\mathscr{F}$ is a singleton. To see this, suppose that $x,y\in\bigcap\mathscr{F}$, and $x\ne y$. If $X$ is Hausdorff, there are disjoint open sets $V$ and $W$ such that $x\in W$ and $y\in V$. But then the argument in the previous paragraph shows that $V\in\mathscr{U}$ and $W\in\mathscr{U}$, which is absurd.

Comment: So if I’m reading this correctly, every ultrafilter on a *compact* $X$ is in fact principal?

Comment: @RiversMcForge: Not quite: every ultrafilter on a compact *Hausdorff* space is principal. If, for instance, $\mathscr{U}$ is a free ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$ with the cofinite topology, which is only $T_1$, $\operatorname{cl}U=\Bbb N$ for each $U\in\mathscr{U}$, and $\mathscr{U}$ converges to every $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: Here's the nub of confusion for me. If I take $[0, 1]$ in the usual topology, then every ultrafilter on there is principal (since it's compact Hausdorff). But if I take that same $[0, 1]$ in the discrete topology, then there are nonprincipal ultrafilters. What happens to those discrete nonprincipal ultrafilters when I consider them in the usual topology? Since the underlying set of points is the same, I don't understand how they disappear, or suddenly become populated by a unique $x \in [0, 1]$.

Comment: @RiversMcForge: Ah, now I see your problem. $[0,1]$ has exactly the same ultrafilters no matter what topology you put on it; what changes is which ones converge, and to which points. In any compact topology they all converge, both fixed and free. The free ultrafilters on $[0,1]$ don’t converge in the discrete topology, but in the usual topology they do. For example, let $\mathscr{U}$ be any ultrafilter on $[0,1]$ containing the filterbase $\{(0,x):x\in(0,1)\}$; $\mathscr{U}$ is free, but it converges to $0$.

Comment: OK, let me see if I understand. The ultrafilter $\mathscr{U}$ itself might not be fixed in $[0, 1]$. But when I pass to the sub-filter $\mathscr{F} \subset \mathscr{U}$ consisting of the *closed* sets in $\mathscr{U}$, then $\mathscr{F}$ *is* fixed, and the intersection $\bigcap_{F \in \mathscr{F}} F$ will be a single point $\{ x \}$, as long as the topology I took the closures in is compact Hausdorff. Do I have that right?

Comment: @RiversMcForge: Yes, that’s right. (By the way, for filters in general there’s a difference between *fixed* and *principal*, though they coincide for ultrafilters. A filter $\mathscr{F}$ is fixed if $\bigcap\mathscr{F}\ne\varnothing$, but it’s principal only if it satisfies the stronger condition that $\bigcap\mathscr{F}\in\mathscr{F}$. Let $E$ be the set of even integers, let $\mathscr{F}$ be the cofinite filter on the odd integers, and let $\mathscr{G}=\{E\cup F:F\in\mathscr{F}\}$; then $\mathscr{G}$ is a non-principal fixed filter on $\Bbb Z$, since $\bigcap\mathscr{G}=\notin\mathscr{G}$.)

Answer (score 2):

An ultrafilter (in fact any filter) $F$ converges to $x$ if $F\supseteq (\dot{x} \cap \tau)$ where $\dot{x}$ is the one-point filter of $x$ and $\tau$ is the topology.

The Stone Čech compactification can be constructed in many ways, for example we constructed it over an product of compact spaces, hence it was immediately clear that is compact due to Tychonoff.